# rest post data need to create file on webserver

Tags: php, xml, rest, drupal

I have some XML data that is sent to drupal 8 via http post. These XML data need to create a content type called property. However, the data can not be directly used in a drupal content node, as they not have the drupal data structure.
I think that I instead will need to post to a folder and then use the drupal feeds module to import and then manipulate the data.
But how is it possible to generate a file from a http post data? Or do I have to think in an other direction?
I have found post that have similar challenges but i need a php solution.. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **url encoded or as plain text (ignoring angular brackets and other special characters)** data sent to your server directly and decode and use it there, because probably if you create file it will take time too and read-write sync issues may arise. As data is url encoded or considered as plain text it can be directly manipulated later.

In other case if its required with file only you can use file upload servlet or endpoint for the same.